# NHibernate producing odd sql in a one-to-many collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Given the following configuration:

```xml
<class name="CategoryPerm" table="CUS_BCDynamicContent_CategoryPerms" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="BCDynamicContent.Entities.Category, BCDynamicContent, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Category">
        <column name="CategoryID" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="PortalGroupId">
        <column name="PortalGroupID" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" />
    </property>
    <bag name="GroupMemberships" cascade="none">
        <key column="ParentPrincipalID" property-ref="PortalGroupId" />
        <one-to-many class="BCDynamicContent.Entities.GroupMembership, BCDynamicContent, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </bag>
</class>
<class name="GroupMembership" table="FWK_GroupMembership" lazy="true" mutable="false" >
    <id name="Id">
    </id>
    <property name="ParentPrincipalId">
        <column name="ParentPrincipalID" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="MemberPrincipalId">
        <column name="MemberPrincipalID" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
```

And the classes:

```cs
public class Entity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}


public class CategoryPerm : Entity
{
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid PortalGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<GroupMembership> GroupMemberships { get; set; }

    public CategoryPerm()
    {
        GroupMemberships = new List<GroupMembership>();
    }
}


public class GroupMembership : Entity
{
    public virtual Guid ParentPrincipalId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Guid MemberPrincipalId { get; private set; }

}
```

And the following linq query:

```cs
var categories = (from x in nhs.Linq<CategoryPerm>() where x.GroupMemberships.Any(y => y.MemberPrincipalId == PortalUser.Current.ID) select x ).ToList() ;
```

Why does the sql that NH comes up with look like this: (the problem one being the “exists()” part "where  this_0_.Id = ParentPrincipalID" <-- shouldn't do that)

```sql
SELECT this_.Id            as Id290_0_,
       this_.CategoryID    as CategoryID290_0_,
       this_.PortalGroupID as PortalGr3_290_0_
FROM   CUS_BCDynamicContent_CategoryPerms this_
WHERE  this_.Id in (SELECT this_0_.Id as y0_
                    FROM   CUS_BCDynamicContent_CategoryPerms this_0_
                           inner join FWK_GroupMembership y1_
                             on this_0_.PortalGroupID = y1_.ParentPrincipalID
                    WHERE  exists(select 1
                                  from   FWK_GroupMembership
                                  where  this_0_.Id = ParentPrincipalID)
                           and y1_.MemberPrincipalID = 'b32f5d6c-490c-45e9-874a-c4d27d2862b8' /* @p0 */)
```

Comment: for the linq query you have given the generated SQL looks correct, it is being generated for the `Any` api that you have used

Comment: It is very close to correct, but not quite.  Note where it says "this_0_.Id = ParentPrincipalID".  It should say "this_0_.PortalgroupID = ParentPrinciplalID" just like it does in the join in the from in the parent SQL.  So linq is respecting the columns for the parent > child for most of the statement except in the "exists" portion where it seems to simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in the NH 2.x Linq provider.  I ended up going to ICriteria instead and now it works like a charm.

```
nhs.CreateCriteria<CategoryPerm>("a").CreateCriteria("a.Category", "b").CreateCriteria("a.GroupMemberships", "c").Add(
                Restrictions.Eq("c.MemberPrincipalId", PortalUser.Current.ID.AsGuid)).List<CategoryPerm>();
```